# Almost all the cloud service providers have 99.95% of data available on the cloud. What will happen if the whole region sinks in an earthquake?

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, cloud, ibm-cloud, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm just asking this question to satisfy my curiosity on cloud development. There's one thing in common in the cloud when comes to data availability, 99.95% of data is subject to be available even during downtime. I want just to know what will happen for example if the entire region sinks in a earthquake.

I understand the fact that there's continous data backup on the cloud storages. are those storages reside in a region or not?

Comment: A "Region" typically (except for Microsoft) contains multiple data centers, each of which are sufficiently separated so that a disaster should not befall all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a couple of examples:

**Amazon S3** is provided on a regional level. That means that when an **S3** bucket is created, AWS automatically uses the different **Availability Zones** in that region to keep the data available.

In the catastrophic case where all the AZs in a region were to be destroyed, then that data will be lost.  For that, **S3** offers **Cross-Region replication** where objects are copied across Amazon S3 buckets in different AWS Regions.

**Google Cloud Storage** is a also a regional service with multi-AZ availability. Google also offers special geo-redundancy in the form of `multi-regional` and `dual-regional` Cloud Storage locations. The USA, for example is designated as a `multi-region` across all its data centers, while Finland and the Netherlands are a specific pair in a `dual-region`:

Comment: Thanks Adi, very clear and helpful.